# How to create an “unlimited” number of independent timers as individual list items in an unordered list with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, timer

I am trying to write a function which when executed (e.g. user clicks a button or image) creates and displays a new timer as a new list item in an unordered list (jQuery Sortable list).  It doesn’t need to be super accurate so SetInterval should work fine. It doesn’t need any stops or resets. I would like the user to be able to create as many new independent (count-up) timers (as list items) in the list as they want, theoretically (although in reality there will likely be less than 10-15 on the go at the same time).

The following code does achieve this (or at least does the first time it is run). Subsequent clicks cause grief as I suspect that the same id is being used more than once for both “minutes” and “seconds” causing a conflict between list items.

```
function listTimer() {
    
    var sec = 0;
    
    function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
    setInterval (function(){    
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));
    }, 1000);
        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sortable1").append('<li class="ui-state-default">' + '<span id="minutes">' + '' + '</span>' + ':' + '<span id="seconds">' + '' + '</span>' + '</li>');      
    }); 
}
```

To allow multiple timers I then figured that each time the function is executed, the values should increment so they are seen as separate. As such I tried

```
Var i = 0;

function listTimer() {
    
    var sec = 0;
    
    function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
    setInterval (function(){    
        document.getElementById("seconds"+i).innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
        document.getElementById("minutes"+i).innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));
    }, 1000);
        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sortable1").append('<li class="ui-state-default">' + '<span id="minutes"+i>' + '' + '</span>' + ':' + '<span id="seconds"+i>' + '' + '</span>' + '</li>');
    
i=++;   
    }); 
}
```

The “seconds” + i  ( and “minutes” =i ) in the .innerHTML works because if I leave var i=0 and then hard code “seconds0” and “minutes0” (instead of “seconds”+i etc) in the span id, a timer is generated as planned  (once). The trick is that the “seconds” + i (and “minutes” =i ) in the span id do not work as I imagined. If I leave it as per the code above (e.g. in both the .innerHTML and span id) no list item is generated. I suspect the problem is in incrementing the span id.

Addressing the “span id=” to increment it (multiple ways) does not seem to have helped.

I have tried declaring and inserting a variable with no luck:

```
var newSeconds= “seconds” +i;
var newMinutes= “seconds” +i;

        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sortable1").append('<li class="ui-state-default">' + '<span id=newMinutes >' + '' + '</span>' + ':' + '<span id=newSeconds>' + '' + '</span>' + '</li>');
```

I have tried changing the id of the span just prior to the append with either:

```
document.getElementById("seconds").setAttribute("id", "seconds" +i);
document.getElementById("minutes").setAttribute("id", "minutes" + i);
```

or

```
document.getElementById("seconds").id("seconds" +i);
document.getElementById("minutes").id ("minutes" + i);
```

or

```
var newSeconds= “seconds” +i;
var newMinutes= “seconds” +i;

document.getElementById("seconds").setAttribute("id", newSeconds);
document.getElementById("minutes").setAttribute("id", newMinutes);
```

or by combinations of these e.g putting quotation marks around the newSeconds/newMinutes in both the .id and .setAttribute.

but I can’t seem to make the append method work and create a new independent list timer each time the trigger is clicked. The timers jump all over the place (or not at all) when the function is executed multiple times.

I have tried searching for javascript or jQuery ways of doing this but I can only seem to see previous questions that revolve around a certain number of timers (and hard coding them e.g. timer1, timer2 etc) rather than an "unlimited" number of timers. I have looked at books on Javascript and jQuery but can't seem to nut out the solution.

I am hoping I have given a minimal reproducible example. I am obviously missing fundamental issues but am unconscious incompetent at the moment. Is anyone happy to show me the error of my ways and help me get the function working?

Comment: It should be `"minutes'+i+'"` and not `"minutes"+i`, but the better approach would be anyway to use classes and keep a reference to the `<li>` element in a local variable before appending it and then refer to the relevant children of it using the `find` (in jQuery) or `querySelector` (in vanilla js) and the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue stems from your referring to the timers by their `Id` attributes - an `Id` attribute is supposed to appear once per page, so having it appear in each timer will definitely cause some confusion.

I would recommend a different structure as well for organization. Here are my thoughts in pseudocode (leaving the implementation up to you)

```js
const $timerContainerDiv = $("…"); // the place where timers live

var timers = []; // this is an array containing all of your timers

// function to add a new timer to the array
var addTimer = function(int minutes, int seconds, int title) {

  // html that defines the actual structure of the timer, 
  // including elements for hours and minutes, each identifiable
  // by a js class, and each one including a data attribute giving its value
  // for example:
  var $timer = $("<div class='timer' data-minutes='" + minutes + "' data-seconds='" + seconds + "' title='" + title + "'>");  
  timers.push(timer);  
}

// now define a timer function to update all timers once per second
var updateTimers = function() {
  
  // update each timer, decrementing one second
  $.each(timers, function(index, val) {
     var $timer = $(val);
     var minutes = $timer.data("minutes");
     var seconds = $timer.data("seconds");
     var title = $timer.attr("title");
     seconds--;
     // need logic for when seconds goes negative to reset to 59 and decrement minutes
     // need logic for when timer done, etc
     $timer.empty();
     $timer.append("<span>" + title + ": " + minutes + ":" + seconds + " remaining</span>");
   });

   setTimeout(updateTimers,1000); // call itself
}

updateTimers(); // get the whole thing started
```